# same function Multiple Names without Wrappers

Tags: c++, oop, wrapper, naming

I am creating a small Linear Algebra Library for educational purposes.

I have a function called A . These function are doing mathematical operations , and they are given different names by different communities. One name for Machine Learning people(say A) , another name for Statistics people(say B).

I want both of them to be able to access the function using the different names that they use , ie both A(...) and B(...) should give the same result. The obvious way is to use a function wrapper.

```
B(...)
{
   return A(...)
}
```

This will get the job done. But is this the right way to do this ? Is there a better more "elegant" way to do this ?

-Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use function pointers.

```
int f1(int a)
{
    return a * 2;
}

const auto f2 = f1;

int main()
{
    cout << f2(4) << endl;
}
```